# How to dynamically inject custom info section into magento sales order view page (without modifying template)?

Tags: php, magento

I am working on a module that creates custom order attribute on sales order. I have achieved it like this:

```
<?php

// Init installer
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;

// Attribute Template
$attribute  = array
(
    'type'            => 'varchar',
    'backend_type'    => 'varchar',
    'frontend_input'  => 'varchar',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label'           => '',
    'visible'         => true,
    'required'        => false,
    'user_defined'    => false,
    'searchable'      => false,
    'filterable'      => false,
    'comparable'      => false,
    'default'         => ''
);

// Sales Rep Attribute
$sales_rep_attribute = $attribute;
$sales_rep_attribute['label'] = 'Sales Rep';
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'sales_rep', $sales_rep_attribute);

// Delivery Date Attribute
$delivery_date_attribute = $attribute;
$delivery_date_attribute['label'] = 'Delivery Date';
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'delivery_date', $delivery_date_attribute);

// PPH Payment Type Attribute
$pph_payment_type_attribute = $attribute;
$pph_payment_type_attribute['label'] = 'PPH Payment Type';
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'pph_payment_type', $pph_payment_type_attribute);

// PPH Invoice Id Attribute
$pph_invoice_id_attribute = $attribute;
$pph_invoice_id_attribute['label'] = 'PPH Invoice Id';
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'pph_invoice_id', $pph_invoice_id_attribute);

// PPH Tx Id Attribute
$pph_tx_id_attribute = $attribute;
$pph_tx_id_attribute['label'] = 'PPH Tx Id';
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'pph_tx_id', $pph_tx_id_attribute);

// Finish installer
$installer->endSetup();
```

After creating these attributes, I tried setting the `delivery date` for e.g. and it saves against the order and I am able to retrieve it.

I would like to show these custom order attributes in the order view page in magento backend. I know you can do this by editing this file: `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml` and add this:

```
<?php if($_order->getDeliveryDate()): ?>
<tr>
    <td class=”label”><label><?php echo Mage::helper(‘sales’)->__(‘Delivery Date’) ?></label></td>
    <td class=”value”><strong><?php echo $_order->getDeliveryDate(); ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But this is manual labour. The order view template could also be over written by another module.

Is it possible to make my module simply injects the additional order view section to the page without any manual edits? How should I go about doing this?

Comment: You should be able to add a reference to a custom block which renders this content from your custom module, into the layout file that defines how the `sales_order_view` handle should render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a little extension of your own, that will be capable of adding an extra block with your info to the sales_order_view layout.

That will let you avoid conflicts with other extensions.

The contents of your layout-file (/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/your_module_name.xml) should be somewhat like this:

```
<layout>    
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="your_module_name/adminhtml_sales_order_view_additional" template="your/module/name/additional_info.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

Add the data you need inside of the template. Also, you can add your java script that will place your block anywhere on the sales_order_view page.